# how to split a string containing URL?

Tags: android

I have a String which has a url and i am getting intent value (also a String) from different activity and appending it to the url which has image names
for example :

```
String imgURL = "http://182.118.18.200:8082/Server/Images/Gallery/" +  
                 images;
```

and i want to display the images from the above string into the viewpager so that i can scroll the images horizontally.
So i am doing this

```
String[] imgUrls = imgURL.split(",");
adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getBaseContext(), imgUrls);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

While debugging the index[0] is showing properly with the url and image name. 
for example :

```
"http://182.118.18.200:8082/Server/Images/Gallery/apple.jpg"
```

but the second index is showing only the imagename , but i want the second index also to be displayed like the first index.
If there is another way other than using String[] imgURLS ,please tell me how to achieve the above.
Thanking You

Comment: I suppose that `images` has a value something like: "apple.jpg,cherry.jpg", etc... isn´t it?

Comment: yes sir you are right

Comment: then... do you see the error?

Comment: you have to split the value before adding it to the url so u build complete urls for all them images

Comment: please post your images array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if images is a string containing images separated by comma (for example "apples.jpg,tomatoes.jpg..."

You can do this:

```
String[] pics = images.split(",");

//I use StringBuilder because String is immutable and this is better to build a dynamic one

StringBuilder urlsString = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<pics.length; i++)
{
    urlsString.append("http://182.118.18.200:8082/Server/Images/Gallery/").append(pics[i]);

    if(i<pics.length-1) urlsString.append(",");
}

 adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getBaseContext(), urlsString.toString().split(","));
 viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: sir , split is not supported by stringbuilder i guess

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten a little detail (just add .toString() before the split, I have now corrected it)

Answer (score 0):

try this for loop to add this url to all.

```
for(int i =0;i<imgUrls.length;i++){
            imgURL = "http://182.118.18.200:8082/Server/Images/Gallery/" + imgUrls[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `images` contains comma separated image names so In your adapter pass image names instead of imageurl(because `imgURL` prefix is same for all images) as

```
String[] imgs= images.split(",");
adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getBaseContext(), imgs);
```

and in your `CustomPagerAdapter` construct your url as

```
String imgUrl = "http://182.118.18.200:8082/Server/Images/Gallery/" + imgs[i];
```

where `i` should be position.